# PHP: Move uploaded file to a dynamically created path

Tags: php, actionscript-3

In this PHP code I'm going to upload a file (sent from AS3) to a directory that already created for each user with same name his username. The problem is that I don't know how to move the file into a folder associated to a user. If a user doesn't have his own folder, some code should be able to get the user's name from $_SESSION['myusername'] and then dynamically create it and then move the file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username =$_SESSION['myusername'];
$uploads_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/'.'/$username/';
if ( ! is_dir($uploads_dir)) {
    mkdir($uploads_dir); 
}  

if( $_FILES['Filedata']['error'] == 0 ){
    if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'],
         $uploads_dir.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'] ) ){
        exit();
    }
}
echo 'error';
exit();
?>
```

But this code move file into "upload" directory and if the uploaded file name be xxx then file name change to xxx$username. How can do this please?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, you just need to also add the file name to the end of your path, something like:

```
$uploads_dir = "upload/".$username."/".$_FILES['Filedata']['name']
```

Then use `move_uploaded_file()` like so:

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'],
         $uploads_dir )
```

Also, its always a good idea to go ahead and make sure the directory exists before hand with `file_exists()`.
I've also found that `move_uploaded_file()` likes full paths for the destinations, you can use `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` to get this

Comment: Thanks.But the files goes into _upload_ directory not the specific users directories still and only file name changed. OK, i already create the directory and tested what you say.

Comment: another side note, beware of whitespaces in any of your paths

Comment: If they are still going into the "upload" directory with the username as the file name then you are most likely missing a back slash...verify the destination path that you send to move_uploaded_files() before you make the call

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand clearly what is your mean? I tried a lot but it doesn't work.

Comment: I want if a user doesn't have his own folder, some code dynamically create it and then upload file:                             $uploads_dir = "./upload/"."$username/";
if ( ! is_dir($uploads_dir)) {
    mkdir($uploads_dir);
}

Comment: You seem to have the right approach, without having the code in front of me all I can suggest is to make sure and use full paths (tack on $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to the beginning of the dest path. Make sure there are no whitespaces in any of the paths, and lastly verify that you have the permission to actually create a directory and write to that directory. If all that is taken care of and it still isnt working without errors than there is something else going on...